# jQuery remove duplicate but keep last occurance

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, each

SO is full of these questions, I know, but after going through 20+ pages and numerous google searches I end up asking because I can't find the answer.

I want to filter through data attributes and keep the last occurrence. So for instance with this code:

```html
<div data-id="001">Hello</div>
<div data-id="001">World</div>
<div data-id="002">Keep</div>
<div data-id="002">Only</div>
<div data-id="002">Unique</div>
<div data-id="003">Last</div>
<div data-id="003">Word</div>
<div data-id="004">Please</div>

<br><br>
<p>Result should be: World Unique Word Please</p>
```

I tried numerous ideas from the SO pages and google searches but I have no luck in keeping the last items. First items though work perfectly with this code.

```js
var found = {};
$('[data-id]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(found[$this.data('id')]){
         $this.remove();   
    }
    else{
         found[$this.data('id')] = true;   
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle, hopefully that makes things easier http://jsfiddle.net/hx9Lzqf6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the last index with same id,store them into an array,then call `$.each()` again to remove elements with index not in the array

```js
let result = {}
$('[data-id]').each(function(i,e){
  let id = $(e).attr("data-id")
  result[id] = i
});
result = Object.values(result)

$('[data-id]').each(function(i,e){
  let id = $(e).attr("data-id")
  if(!result.includes(i)){
   $(e).remove() 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="001">Hello</div>
<div data-id="001">World</div>
<div data-id="002">Keep</div>
<div data-id="002">Only</div>
<div data-id="002">Unique</div>
<div data-id="003">Last</div>
<div data-id="003">Word</div>
<div data-id="004">Please</div>

<br><br>
<p>Result should be: World Unique Word Please</p>
```